# Connection errors when making requests to local server from Android

Tags: php, android, json

I am building an app that parsers json into a listview from a database. I have used a PHP script to encode the data from the database in the JSON format below:

```
[
 {"id":"1","artistname":"Rihanna"},
 {"id":"2","artistname":"Katy Perry"},
 {"id":"3","artistname":"DJ Dibs"},
 {"id":"4","artistname":"Jamie Foxx"},
 {"id":"5","artistname":"Disclosure"}

]
```

Here is the parser class which returns the data above as a string:

```
    package com.example.jsontester;

     public class JsonParser {
     static InputStream is = null;
     static JSONObject jsonObject = null;
     static String data = "";


     public JsonParser() {

     }

     public String getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

     // Making HTTP request
     try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();            

     } 
     catch (UnsupportedEncodingException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
     } catch (ClientProtocolException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
     } catch (IOException exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
     }

     //Gets the JSON String
     try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

        StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        //Appends the string to the line
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        data = sBuilder.toString();

      } 

      catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
      }


     return data;

    }
   }
```

Here is the activity which creates the listview with the chart items

```
package com.example.jsontester;

 public class JsonActivity extends ListActivity{

 private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_ITEM = "item";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_ARTISTNAME = "artistname";

 // chartItemList is the array list that holds the chart items 
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>> chartItemList = 
         new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Integer>>();
    JsonParser Parser = new JsonParser();
 // JSONArray
    JSONArray chartItems = null;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */    
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.progressdialog);

    //url from where the JSON has to be retrieved
    String url = <<http://127.0.0.1/mmcv/>>;

    //Check if the user has a connection

    ConnectivityManager cm = 
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (info != null) {
        if (!info.isConnected()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, 
           "Please check your connection and try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        //if positive, fetch the articles in background
        else new getChartItems().execute(url);
    }

    //else show toast
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please check your connection and try again.", 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

class getChartItems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    // Shows a progress dialog while executing background task
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(JsonActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading chart...");
        progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    //Gets the json data for chart items data and presents it in a list view
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String url = <<http://127.0.0.1/mmcv>>;
        String json = Parser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        System.out.println("Json should be below me");
        System.out.println(json);
        int id;

        String artistname;

        try{

        chartItems = new JSONArray(json);

        JSONObject json_data=null;

         for(int i=0;i<chartItems.length();i++){

            json_data = chartItems.getJSONObject(i);

            artistname=json_data.getString("TAG_ARTISTNAME");
            id=json_data.getInt("TAG_ID");


             HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
             // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                hashMap.put(artistname,id);

             // adding HashMap to ArrayList
                chartItemList.add(hashMap);

         }
        }

        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

             //updating list view with the parsed items
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(JsonActivity.this, chartItemList,
                R.layout.listview,
                new String[] { TAG_ID, TAG_ARTISTNAME }, new int[] {R.id.id, 
                    R.id.artistname });
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    //Removes the progress dialog when the data has been fetched
    protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}



 }
```

Here is the logcat:

```
01-19 15:45:49.816: D/libEGL(29490): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-19 15:45:49.867: W/System.err(29490): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to     

   (http://127.0.0.1) refused
01-19 15:45:49.898: D/libEGL(29490): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-19 15:45:49.902: D/libEGL(29490): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
01-19 15:45:49.914: W/System.err(29490):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
01-19 15:45:49.918: W/System.err(29490):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-19 15:45:49.925: W/System.err(29490):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-19 15:45:49.925: W/System.err(29490):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
01-19 15:45:49.925: W/System.err(29490):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-19 15:45:49.925: W/System.err(29490):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-19 15:45:49.929: W/System.err(29490):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-19 15:45:49.929: W/System.err(29490):    at com.example.jsontester.JsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(JsonParser.java:36)
01-19 15:45:49.929: W/System.err(29490):    at com.example.jsontester.JsonActivity$getChartItems.doInBackground(JsonActivity.java:83)
01-19 15:45:49.929: W/System.err(29490):    at com.example.jsontester.JsonActivity$getChartItems.doInBackground(JsonActivity.java:1)
01-19 15:45:49.933: W/System.err(29490):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-19 15:45:49.933: W/System.err(29490):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-19 15:45:49.933: W/System.err(29490):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-19 15:45:49.933: W/System.err(29490):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-19 15:45:49.933: W/System.err(29490):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-19 15:45:49.937: W/System.err(29490):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-19 15:45:49.937: W/System.err(29490):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-19 15:45:49.937: W/System.err(29490): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /<<127.0.0.1>> (port 80): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
01-19 15:45:49.941: W/System.err(29490):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
01-19 15:45:49.941: W/System.err(29490):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
01-19 15:45:49.945: W/System.err(29490):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
01-19 15:45:49.945: W/System.err(29490):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
01-19 15:45:49.945: W/System.err(29490):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
01-19 15:45:49.957: W/System.err(29490):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
01-19 15:45:49.957: D/OpenGLRenderer(29490): Enabling debug mode 0
01-19 15:45:49.957: W/System.err(29490):    ... 16 more
01-19 15:45:49.961: W/System.err(29490): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
01-19 15:45:49.972: W/System.err(29490):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
01-19 15:45:49.992: W/System.err(29490):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
01-19 15:45:49.992: W/System.err(29490):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
01-19 15:45:49.992: W/System.err(29490):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
01-19 15:45:49.992: W/System.err(29490):    ... 21 more
01-19 15:45:49.992: W/System.err(29490): java.lang.NullPointerException
01-19 15:45:49.996: W/System.err(29490):    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:64)
01-19 15:45:49.996: W/System.err(29490):    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:79)
01-19 15:45:50.000: W/System.err(29490):    at com.example.jsontester.JsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(JsonParser.java:51)
01-19 15:45:50.000: W/System.err(29490):    at com.example.jsontester.JsonActivity$getChartItems.doInBackground(JsonActivity.java:83)
01-19 15:45:50.007: W/System.err(29490):    at com.example.jsontester.JsonActivity$getChartItems.doInBackground(JsonActivity.java:1)
01-19 15:45:50.011: W/System.err(29490):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-19 15:45:50.011: W/System.err(29490):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-19 15:45:50.023: W/System.err(29490):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-19 15:45:50.031: W/System.err(29490):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-19 15:45:50.031: W/System.err(29490):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-19 15:45:50.035: W/System.err(29490):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-19 15:45:50.035: W/System.err(29490):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
01-19 15:45:50.039: I/System.out(29490): Json should be below me
01-19 15:45:50.050: W/System.err(29490): org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
01-19 15:45:50.125: W/System.err(29490):    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450)
01-19 15:45:50.152: W/System.err(29490):    at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97)
01-19 15:45:50.152: W/System.err(29490):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:87)
01-19 15:45:50.152: W/System.err(29490):    at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:103)
01-19 15:45:50.152: W/System.err(29490):    at com.example.jsontester.JsonActivity$getChartItems.doInBackground(JsonActivity.java:92)
01-19 15:45:50.152: W/System.err(29490):    at com.example.jsontester.JsonActivity$getChartItems.doInBackground(JsonActivity.java:1)
01-19 15:45:50.156: W/System.err(29490):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-19 15:45:50.156: W/System.err(29490):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
01-19 15:45:50.156: W/System.err(29490):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
01-19 15:45:50.156: W/System.err(29490):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-19 15:45:50.156: W/System.err(29490):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
01-19 15:45:50.156: W/System.err(29490):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
01-19 15:45:50.156: W/System.err(29490):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domain 127.0.0.1 causes the device to look for the web server on the device itself.  Use 10.0.2.2 instead.

Here's a link on how to use networking in the emulator

http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking

Comment: Right problem, wrong solution.  10.0.0.2 is a forwarding alias which only works on emualators.

Comment: @ChrisStratton sorry i'm a bit confused, do you mean that neither of them will work?

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast - yes, those forwarding addresses only work on the emulator, not on physical android devices (excepting perhaps rooted ones where someone has set up unusual networking)

Comment: Something I've done to sort of bypass the problem is to use Google App Engine to create a free web server with a domain address and then use that for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You have made the classic mistake of using "localhost" or its numeric form "127.0.0.1" as a universal address.  It is not, rather, it is an aliases for looping back to the same machine on which the program is running.

When you tested your server from a program running on the server, 127.0.0.1 works.  But when you try that from the phone, it tries to contact a server process running on the phone itself.

As AndroidGuy points out, when you run on the Android emulator, there is a special alias address you can use to contact the hosting development machine.  But this is not available for physical Android devices.

You have a few choices, none of them great:

- you can put the android device on the same wifi network as the server, and contact it via its real ip address on the subnet (typically 192.168.0.something).
- you can test against a real server on the publicly routable Internet, using the mobile network connection (or wifi connection) on the device.
- you can attempt to use a tethering capability on the device "backwards" to establish a subnet between the device and the test server, but be very careful you don't accidentally send all the server's other traffic over the mobile network.
- you can play some other game on a rooted device to implement custom traffic routing/proxying
- you can run the server on the android device for testing